# Trying to find all solutions of given equations.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to find all $(a,x,b,y) \in \mathbb{R}^4_{\geq 0}$
satisfying:

$a^2+x^2=b^2+y^2=ax+by$

It is clear that $(t,t,t,t)$
is a solution of given equations for any non negative real number $t$
. Also, if any two numbers from $a,x,b$
and $y$
are equal then all four will be equal. Is there any other solution of given equations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that $$a^2+x^2+b^2+y^2 = 2ax + 2by$$

Rearranging yields $$a^2-2ax+x^2+b^2-2by+y^2 = (a-x)^2 + (b-y)^2 = 0$$

Since squares are non-negative, we must have that $a=x$ and $b=y$.

Thus, we have that $2a^2 = 2b^2$ and thus $a=b$.

This gives us all solutions to be of the form $(t,t,t,t)$.

$\hspace{1cm}$

If we take the restriction of $\mathbb{R}^+_0$ off and as only $\mathbb{R}$, we have $(t,t,\pm t,\pm t)$ where the $\pm$ are dependent of each other.

Comment: Adding as you do : $a^2+b^2\color{red}{+}b^2+y^2$ means that you are working on an "enlarged" set of solutions. You should take this into account in your presentation.

Comment: @JeanMarie, since we have the two equations $a^2+x^2 = ax+by$ and $b^2+y^2 = ax+by$, we can add the two to get $a^2+x^2+b^2+y^2=2ax+2by$.

Comment: I just understood that, sorry, and revised my comment.